# Attributing a specific class to each field of a django-form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form in django and I want to attribute a class to some fields. that's because I want to use those classes in my css code and I don't want all fields have the same style.

for example my form has 2 text fields and a button. I don't want to style the text fields as same as each other. I want the first to be right-to-left and the second to be left-to-right.

we can use `required_css_class = 'required'` but it's just for the required fields and not for every field I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(
               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'40'}))
```

More [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances)